# Pasar información de un gridview a otro formulario

Tags: sql, asp.net, stored-procedure

estoy realizando un proyecto en .net webforms y tengo un gridview el cual tiene un botón de editar, al presionar el botón obtiene el id de la columna y me pasa al form de editar, lo que no logro es traer la info de tal id, ya logre que me redireccione, el proyecto lo estoy realizando en modelo de 3 capas.

*Sección de editar*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son mis entidades:

```
public class listadoinfo
{
  public int folio { get; set; }
   public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }

}
```

Este es mi DAL:

```
 public List<listadoinfo> mostrardatos(listadoinfo pEN) {


  IDbConnection _conn = DBCommon.conexion();
           _conn.Open();

SqlCommand __command = new SqlCommand("GET_SP_INFO", _conn as
SqlConnection);
__command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
__command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@folio", pEN.folio));

 IDataReader _reader = __command.ExecuteReader();
       List<listadoinfo> lista = new List<listadoinfo>();
       while (_reader.Read())
       {

         mostrarofertas.folio = _reader.GetInt32(0);
         mostrarofertas.nombre = !_reader.IsDBNull(1) ? _reader.GetString(1) : "N/A";

         mostrarofertas.tipo = !_reader.IsDBNull(2) ? _reader.GetString(2) : "N/A";

         mostrarofertas.titulo = !_reader.IsDBNull(3) ? _reader.GetString(3) : "N/A";

       }
       _conn.Close();
       return lista;

        }
```

*Este es la BL*

```
      public List<listadoinfo> listado(listadoinfo pEN)
           {
               return ofertas.mostrardatos(pEN);
           }
```

*Parte de editar.aspx.cs*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

          if (!Page.IsPostBack)

          {

          if (!IsPostBack && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["folio"]))

              {

         ViewState["folio"] = Request.QueryString["folio"];

        var folio = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["folio"]);

  }

   else if (!IsPostBack)

            {

  Response.Redirect("~/mostrar.aspx", true);

              }




      }
```

Es correcta la forma en que estoy haciendo la parte DAL para recuperar la información y una cosa más, la que dice Folio hotel es un listbox multiselect, como le haria para recuperar esa info y ponerla ahi de nuevo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -1):

Usa variables de sesión.

```
Session["Variable"]=Dato
```

Luego podrás usar Dato en cualquier formulario así:

```
Suma=Elemento+Session["Variable"]
```

Esto será igual a:

```
Suma=Elemento+Dato
```